# With Java EE and GWT, how can I open a new browser tab to a web app on the same server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

I have a web app that displays a list of ID's (among other things) to the user. The back end is Java EE, and the front end is built with GWT.

When the user clicks one of the ID's a callback is executed that queries additional parameters from an API using the ID. When the API returns the parameters, I want to open another web app, passing one of the parameters to it so it opens displaying information relating to that parameter. How would this normally be done?

Can I use something like [LinkElement](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/LinkElement.html) for this?

**Edit:** I got this working using GWT's `Window.open("my.url.com");`
But I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use GWT's `Window` class to handle this.